# How to get the rows of mySQL based on a visitors path?

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I save the browsed pages of my registered visitors and the referrers.

So each new browsed page has its own row. Also, each row has a column "username" where I save the username of each visitor.

What I want to achieve is to know which visitors had a journey that while browsing the website viewed the `/pricing` page, but also BEFORE that page, they had an entrance `ref` by `Google`.

Honestly I don't have a clue how to make it, but I am trying like below which for now is wrong.

Any heads up please?

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE (ref='Google' or url='/pricing') group by username
```

Comment: Could you show the table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html) to do this.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT username
  FROM pages AS ref_pages
  WHERE ref = 'Google' AND username IN(
      SELECT DISTINCT username FROM pages
      WHERE url = '/pricing' AND time > ref_pages.time
  )
```

Comment: I understand the logic, however it returned me zero results.I think it has something to do with the `ref` column is NULL. However rows containing the url, the `url` column is always filled.

Comment: If you want to ignore NULL columns, add `AND ref IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: To take it to the next step, every row has its own id. I want the `google` id to be found before `/pricing` id. *that means he started from google and then somehow he browsed `pricing`

Comment: See updated answer. You can reference a value in the outer query from the subquery by aliasing the outer query table name. Then compare in the subquery.